# How anonymous is it to use Facebook's Tor-site?

Tags: privacy, tor, facebook

How anonymous, with respect to Facebook, not the rest of the world, is it to use Facebook via https://www.facebookcorewwwi.onion/ rather than the usual site? That is, if two different Facebook users use Facebook from the same instance of Tor Browser, can Facebook identify that these two users are using the same computer and the same network connection if they log in and out without getting a new identity or circuit before logging in again.

Comment: If the answer helped, please mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 4):

> How anonymous [...] is it to use Facebook via https://www.facebookcorewwwi.onion/

This depends on what you mean by anonymous. If you use an account which you had previously logged in using your real IP address, or if the account is in your real name and linkable to your identity, then it is not anonymous. If you mean location anonymity (hiding the location from which you are currently connecting), it is fully anonymous whether or not you are using your real name.

> can Facebook identify that these two users are using the same computer and the same network connection if they log in and out without getting a new identity or circuit before logging in again.

Yes. You need to restart the browser by using the New Identity feature. This will clear out tracking cookies and other identifying material. It is not enough to just switch circuits. You must clear the browser state correctly by selecting New Identity. Note that particularly advanced tracking using JavaScript to identify unique browser characteristics may be able to correlate the identity of two accounts that use the same browser, but it requires an active attack.

Comment: So it is better to use the regular site in two different browsers with Tor button if you want to prevent Facebook from linking these two accounts to each other?

Comment: @hensti I'm not sure what you mean. If you want to avoid linking an identity, you select New Identity to restart the browser.